# problem with index -mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

The relation of `PRIMARY` is equal to `fk_student_single_user1.` So i must remove one of them.

The problem is, i can't remove or rename `PRIMARY` in workbench, the program does not allow, and if i delete `fk_student_single_user1`, i also delete the `foreign key`. The only way is delete `PRIMARY` in the phpmyadmin.

But i think that exists any problem in my eer model, it is supposed an export without bugs.
I deleted my previous column id, because two foreign keys can be the primary key of the table.

How i can solve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the foreign key, dropping the needless fkey index, and re-adding the foreign key using plain sql (`alter table...`) rather than your GUI.

The SQL spec requires a unique index on the target column, so there's no reason to add an extra (non-unique) index on top.

If MySQL still adds the index, you might want to report it as a bug (as well as to http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html).

If not, you might want to investigate whether the index was added by your GUI in the first place. And if so, report the issue as a bug to the GUI's creator.

Comment: the problem has solved. The issue occurs because i want to use two types of foreign keys, one Identified and other that is non - identified. So i solved the problem when i made the two foreign keys as non-identified - basically the same type